# Как растянуть текст на всю длину страницы?

Tags: html, css

Добрый день.

Есть элементарная разметка вида

```html
<p>Это просто какой-то текст</p>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы параграф `<p>...</p>` занимал всю ширину страницы (или какую-то его часть) и при этом размер шрифта масштабировался? Так чтобы при разных размерах окна обозревателя высота шрифта была разной.

Comment: У шрифта нет высоты, его размеры пропорциональны в зависимости от px!

Переобоснуйте вопрос, ибо сейчас он выглядит за гранью фантастики!

А учитывая заголовок вопроса, ответ от @Ёхарный Бабай вполне адекватен!

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но по-моему, тут без JS и только средствами CSS будет сложно справиться.

Comment: Наверное, JS + css свойство [transform](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/matritsa-preobrazovanii) Вам помогут.

Comment: Если вас устраивает один из ответов поставте рядом с ним галочку

Comment: Не пойму. Так текст по умолчанию занимает всю ширину блока, вопрос в размере шрифта. А для адаптивности можно задать в em. Или я что-то не так понял?

Answer (score 3):

Как оказалось, задача элементарно решается в HTML5 с помощью встроенного SVG (проверено в Chrome и Firefox). Пример:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
    preserveAspectRatio="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text x="12.5" y="25" font-size="15">Stretch to fit</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p{
    width:100%;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

Comment: Это не будет работать. [Посмотрите](http://jsfiddle.net/J3ZPB/). Возможно, я неверно выразил свою мысль: нужно, чтобы высота шрифта менялась в зависимости от размеров страницы. Примерно этот эффект можно получить, если сделать фон картинкой, на которой будет текст.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function onres() {
  var browwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  var myp = document.getElementById("myp");
  myp.style.fontSize = browwidth / 5 + "px";
}
window.onresize = onres;
onres();
```

```css
#myp {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  line-height: 100%;
  font-size: 9px;
}
```

```html
<p id="myp">Это просто какой-то текст</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Давайте еще проще

```css
p{font-size:8.5vw;}
```

```html
<p>Это просто какой-то текст</p>
```